# How does NMO reform Osmium tetroxide after reaction with an alkene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

After Osmium tetroxide adds to a double bond and is then hydrolysed the following species is formed:[image]

Because Osmium tetroxide is toxic, NMO is used to transform the above back to Osmium tetroxide. NMO is:[image]

What is the mechanism for this?

Answer (score 5):

N-methyl-morpholine-N-oxide (NMO) is used to reoxidize and regenerate osmium tetroxide ($\ce{OsO4}$) in what is known as the "Upjohn Dihydroxylation" procedure.

Mechanistically, the redox occurs when a lone pair of electrons on the reduced $\ce{Os(VI)O3}$ are used to form a bond to the morpholine N-oxygen; the electrons from the former $\ce{N-O}$ bond are, in turn, transferred to the morpholine nitrogen.  The $\ce{OsO3}$ gains an oxygen and is oxidized back to osmium (VIII) tetroxide and the NMO is reduced to N-methylmorpholine

[image]

[image source](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/upjohn-dihydroxylation.shtm)

Osmium tetroxide is both toxic and expensive. Using the Upjohn procedure allows the reaction to be run with a catalytic amount of osmium teroxide and 1 equivalent of NMO.